# Icomoon как сделать иконку прозрачной? чтобы был background у иконки, а сама иконка transparent?

Tags: css

вот чтобы примерно так выглядело http://prntscr.com/rqpnbu

Comment: скиньте, пожалуйста, код (html+css)

Comment: Я могу скинуть пример без icomoon ....хотите?